# I'm trying to modify this function to check if a word is a palindrome, I'm using CodeRunner. but what do these errors mean?

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

Im doing a practice task trying to make a function that checks, if a string is a palindrome or not.
here's the code:

```
int IsPalindrome(char *word)
// C program to check if a string is a palindrome.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int IsPalindrome(char *word)
{
// Start from left and
// right corners of str
int z = 0;
int h = strlen(word) - z;

// Keep comparing characters
// while they are same
while (h > z)
{
    if (word[z++] != word[h--])
    {
        printf("0");
        return;
    }
}
printf("1");
}
```

the code sunning service being used is super srict and I don't understand the errors.

errors-

```
Syntax Error(s)
__tester__.c: In function 'IsPalindrome':
__tester__.c:18:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
 {
 ^
__tester__.c:37:12: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
 int main() {
            ^
__tester__.c:113:1: error: expected '{' at end of input
 }
 ^
__tester__.c:113:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors.
```

the test input looks like this:

char word[100] = "a";
printf("%d", IsPalindrome(word));

the result should either be a 1 or a 0.

Comment: In the very first iteration of your loop, `word[h--]` will be the string null-terminator.

Comment: You're missing a `;` after the declaration of the `IsPalindrome` function in the first line.

Comment: As for your problem, is the code you show us a proper [mre], copy-pasted as-is, from the actual code you attempt to build?

Comment: Also, what is `IsPalindrome` supposed to return? You declare it to return an `int` value, but it doesn't actually return any values.

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

`word[strlen(word)]`

is always '\0'

```
int IsPalindrome(char *word)
```

Where ';'?

Comment: While true, it's not the cause of the compiler error the OP is asking about.